# Fetching single row result without iterating in loop from Mysql using Java

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have a simple query that returns only count of rows.

```
select count(*) cnt from table
```

I can read it by iterating through resultset.

like

```
while(rs.next()){
  int rowCount= rs.getInt(cnt);
}
```

But is there any way,using which I can get count directly without looping.

Comment: Longer answer: [YES](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21476846/474189)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
int rowCount = rs.next() ? rs.getInt(cnt) : -1;
```

It doesn't save you much though

Comment: I wouldn't return `0`. I'd throw an exception to demonstrate something went wrong while obtaining the row value. No response != no rows.

Comment: Possibly, but I'd leave that to the developer. It depends on his expectations of the call.

Comment: I guess `-1` might be a sensible value if you want to avoid exceptions. That's a classic "something is amiss" value.

Comment: Ok, agree on that. It does make sense to indicate that we couldn't get an answer

Comment: It doesn't save much indeed, but it is a lot cleaner. When you select a count, it is a safe assumption there is one row.