# Resultset not working in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table like this

Signup table

```
Login_id   Address  User_type  state 

    1      Ansari     s        Alaska
    2      Rajesh     b        Rameshwaram
```

---

```
String retrieve_query="select User_type from Signup where State="Alaska";                           
ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(retrieve_query);

String User_type=rs1.getString("User_type");//I expect "S" to be the User_type
```

But i am getting the following exception

**Exception occured java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed**

Comment: Execute query return a array from db you must fetch it and iterate

Comment: @Laurentiu i am using the condition directly in my select statement ,so i don't wish to iterate.I want the exact ResultSet rs1 without iterating .Can you suggest

Comment: I'm assuming `String retrieve_query="select User_type from Signup where State="Alaska";  ` is not the actual SQL, since it won't pass compilation.

Comment: @VijayIndia As mentioned in my answer, you are missing `rs1.next()`.

Comment: Yes, check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21476846/3270074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `rs1.next()`.

```
String User_type=null;
if (rs1.next()) 
    User_type = rs1.getString("User_type");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps;
ResultSet rs;
String user_type=null;
ps = con.prepareStatement("select User_type from Signup where State='?'");
ps.setString(1, "Alaska");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) 
   user_type = rs.getString("User_type");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace you're query with:

```
String retrieve_query="select User_type from Signup where State='Alaska'";
```